# How to join tables only for the last date before a specific date?

Tags: ms-access

Basically t1 look something like this

```
DATE       Profile   PCS
1/2/2019   DIE6660   8
1/2/2019   DIE9240   9
2/2/2019   DIE9240   7
2/2/2019   DIT8990   1
2/2/2019   DIT6690   5
3/2/2019   DIE6770   2
4/2/2019   DIE9240   6
```

And t2 look like this

```
DATE      Profile  CON
1/2/2019  DIE9240  B
2/2/2019  DIE9240  B
2/2/2019  DIT6690  B
3/2/2019  DIE6770  N
4/2/2019  DIE9240  N
```

So I want to join those tables but it must be that the t2 ID joins with the last date before the t1 ID

So basically the "DIE9240" in "4/2/2019" in t2 must join with the "DIE9240" in "2/2/2019" in t1. It cannot join with the one in "4/2/2019" because it is the same date (not before it), neither with "1/2/2019" because it is not the last date before it.

Is there anyway to do that? Much appreciated

This is what I have tried as shown in the sql view

```
SELECT *
FROM t1 INNER JOIN t2
ON
t2.profile = t1.profile 
and
t1.date = (select max(date) from t1 where profile = t2.profile and date 
< t2.date)
```

Comment: So what is the result of what you have tried?  Please explain why your solution is not working.  Please do that by editing the question rather than explaining such details in comments.

Comment: Two immediate hints: (1) Do NOT use keywords and VBA function names as column names, like `date`.  Access even warns of this when creating such a named column in the table design view.  If you insist, then at least delimit it properly in SQL using brackets like `[date]`.  (2) Use table aliases for nested queries AND qualify all columns with the table name.  Example:  `select max(t1B.[date]) from t1 AS t1B where t1B.profile = t2.profile and t1B.[date] < t2.[date]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query1: Pulls date from previous record for each profile group.

`SELECT (SELECT TOP 1 Dupe.date FROM t1 AS Dupe 
WHERE Dupe.profile = t1.profile AND Dupe.date < t1.date ORDER BY Dupe.date DESC) AS PD, *
FROM t1;`

Query2: Join Query1 to t2 with compound join. Join either the Query1.PD and t2.Date fields or Query1.Date and t2.Date fields depending on the desired output.

`SELECT Query2.Date, Query2.PD, Query2.Profile, Query2.PCS, t2.CON
FROM t2 INNER JOIN Query2 ON (t2.Date = Query2.PD) AND (t2.Profile = Query2.Profile);`